# Auth0 verification email not sending email parameter in return URL parameters

Tags: auth0

I have auth0 setup to send a Verification Email (using Link) and a redirect URL - http://localhost:3000/app/registration

When I create a user it’s working and they get the email, and it redirects with this URL:

```
http://localhost:3000/app/registration?supportSignUp=true&supportForgotPassword=true&message=Your%20email%20was%20verified.%20You%20can%20continue%20using%20the%20application.&success=true&code=success#
```

The problem is: according to [this link](https://auth0.com/docs/brand-and-customize/email/customize-email-templates?_ga=2.15761398.1391730041.1636391377-2041474324.1635861123&_gl=1*5wn5ph*rollup_ga*MjA0MTQ3NDMyNC4xNjM1ODYxMTIz*rollup_ga_F1G3E656YZ*MTYzNjY2NTgzNS4yMy4wLjE2MzY2NjU4MzYuNTk.#configuring-the-redirect-to-url), it should include the email address of the registered user; however, it is not. Is there a reason for this? If I could simply pass the email, I could make an API call and complete the registration process through the auth0 API.

My intention is to send the user to a special registration page on my single page application site where they can finish the registration process and set their password. Any help with this would be appreciated - thanks!

Comment: I don't fully understand the problem, what is working and what not? Can you pinpoint the issue in more detail please?

Comment: encounter the same problem, do you have any clue yet?